# upgrade plone 3.3.6 to plone 4.0.7 File Error

Tags: migration, plone

i tried to migrate plone 3.3.6 to a newer plone 4.0.7 version (and then to 4.3.x) but I ran in multiple errors:

[Full traceback](http://pastebin.com/wWhvYWza)

```
2013-10-07 13:51:33 INFO ProgressHandler Process started (1842 objects to go)
2013-10-07 13:51:33 ERROR plone.app.upgrade Upgrade aborted. Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/iie/Projects/plone4.0/rwa/eggs/Plone-4.0.7-py2.6.egg/Products/CMFPlone/MigrationTool.py", line 175, in upgrade
    step['step'].doStep(setup)
  File "/Users/iie/Projects/plone4.0/rwa/eggs/Products.GenericSetup-1.6.3-py2.6.egg/Products/GenericSetup/upgrade.py", line 142, in doStep
    self.handler(tool)
  File "/Users/iie/Projects/plone4.0/rwa/eggs/plone.app.upgrade-1.0.7-py2.6.egg/plone/app/upgrade/v40/betas.py", line 117, in updateIconMetadata
    obj = brain.getObject()
  File "/Users/iie/Projects/plone4.0/rwa/eggs/Zope2-2.12.18-py2.6-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/Products/ZCatalog/CatalogBrains.py", line 92, in getObject
    target = parent.restrictedTraverse(path[-1])
  File "/Users/iie/Projects/plone4.0/rwa/eggs/Zope2-2.12.18-py2.6-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/OFS/Traversable.py", line 310, in restrictedTraverse
    return self.unrestrictedTraverse(path, default, restricted=True)
  File "/Users/iie/Projects/plone4.0/rwa/eggs/Zope2-2.12.18-py2.6-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/OFS/Traversable.py", line 278, in unrestrictedTraverse
    raise e
AttributeError: pa_20120810.pdf
```

If I delete "pa_20120810.pdf" another file throws an error, and so on ...
I hope you understand me and someone can help me

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something to try: before migration use [collective.catalogcleanup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.catalogcleanup) to remove broken references from your catalog. It's easy to use: add to your buildout, restart the site, go to `/@@collective-catalogcleanup?dry_run=false` in your browser.

As collective.catalogcleanup's documentation states:

> The goal is to get rid of outdated brains that could otherwise cause problems, for example during an upgrade to Plone 4.